# How to sample point from triangle where vertex is not in origin

Tags: statistics, optimization

This link http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrianglePointPicking.html gives an overview of how to sample points from either a quadrilateral or triangle given one vertex is at the origin.  The standard formula is:  $x=a_{1}v_{1}+a_{2}v_{2}$ where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are from the distribution $U(0,1)$. Also, I am not sure of the intuition behind this formula as to why this yields random samples.

EDIT: I know you simply add the offset vertex if the vertex is not in the origin. But the point is then contained in the quadrilateral. If I only want the points formed by a particular triangle in the quadrilateral, do I simply reject points that are not inside the vertices of the triangle?

Answer (score 2):

If you continue reading the article you linked to, it says "The points not in the triangle interior can then either be discarded, or transformed into the corresponding point inside the triangle (right figure)." By "transformed", they mean that you apply a geometrical transformation to the points in the wrong half of the quadrilateral (the ones with $a_1+a_2\gt1$), e.g. reflect them in the diagonal dividing the two triangles (corresponding to $a_2'=1-a_1$ and $a_1'=1-a_2$) or rotate them by $\pi$ about the centre of the quadrilateral (corresponding to $a_1'=1-a_1$ and $a_2'=1-a_2$).

Comment: Is there any way to generate points in a triangle using the unit circle?

Comment: @lord12: I'm not sure what you mean by "using the unit circle". If you mean that you're able to generate points uniformly distributed in the unit disk and you want to use that to generate points uniformly distributed in a triangle, the answer is yes: Place the triangle inside the disk, choose points uniformly from the disk, and discard them if they lie outside the triangle.

Comment: This is similar to just drawing a square around the triangle and rejecting points outside the triangle. I actually found another result from this paper http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~funk/tog02.pdf, that states $P = (1 - \sqrt{r_1}) A + (\sqrt{r_1} (1 - r_2))  B + (r_2 \sqrt{r_1}) C$ is uniformly distributed but I cannot understand why.

Comment: @lord12: Since the width of the triangle grows linearly as you move from $A$ to $BC$, the cumulative distribution function of the corresponding coordinate $r_1$ is quadratic; thus inverting it leads to a square root.

Comment: I see. This is an application of the inverse transformation method.